# Cannot Execute SQL Query in a .map()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have an endpoint that receives an array in the req.body. I need to fetch that array and for each element of that array, i need to execute the SQL Update Query. This is the code:

```
const approveShifts = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { guard_id } = req.params;
    const { shiftIDs, isBooked } = req.body;
    shiftIDs.map((shift_id) => {
      connection.query(
        `UPDATE shift SET isBooked=${isBooked}, fk_guard=${guard_id} WHERE shiftID=${shift_id}`,
        (err, rows) => {
          if (!err) {
            res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              message: `Successfully Approved Shift #${shift_id} for Guard #${guard_id}`,
            });
          } else {
            res.status(404).json({
              success: false,
              message: "Shift Not Found!",
            });
          }
        }
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

This is my req.body:

```
{
    "shiftIDs": [64],
    "isBooked": 1
}
```

The issue is, no matter what kind of testing i do, the only output i get is "Shift Not Found!" from the else statement of the query. Nothing else happens. I can't get it to work. Can someone guide me ?

Comment: "Shift Not Found" means you've got an error (your code executed the `else` part). Can you log that error and see what it says?

Comment: Note that you are performing an asynchronous task in a synchronous manner. `map` is synchronous. `query` is asynchronous. You also shouldn't use `map` unless you're using the resulting array. If you just want to iterate, use `forEach`. Note also that this will return a 200 status for the first updated shift. I'm not sure if Node.js or express will continue processing further queries once you call `res.status()`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tried it with the forEach also, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here- firstly I recommend you use prepared statements instead of string templates for your query:

```
// (assuming this is mysql client?)

connection.query('UPDATE shift SET isBooked = ?, fk_guard = ? WHERE shiftID = ?', [isBooked, guard_id, shift_id], (err, rows, fields) => {...})

// if it's the mysql2 client, use connection.execute() instead of connection.query()
```

This works by replacing each `?` with the value in the array, in order. This will help avoid SQL injection problems.

Secondly, you can do this in 1 query instead of mapping by using the `IN` SQL operator because you are setting the same value for isBooked and fk_guard for every shiftID:

```
// assuming shiftIDs is an array

connection.query('UPDATE shift SET isBooked = ?, fk_guard = ? WHERE shiftID IN (?)', [isBooked, guard_id, shiftIDs], (err, rows, fields) => {...});
```

And as someone else said, you should `console.log(err)` right before `res.status(404)` to see what the error is. And by the way, if the shift doesn't exist, no rows will be updated but no error will be thrown either, so your response wouldn't be 404.

Comment: your solution was intuitive, as you said, i can do this in a single query without needing a looping mechanism. I tried but it didn't work. What can be the cause of this ? i tried logging the error but the output still doesn't change.

Comment: i have updated the question to include the req.body also, please check in accordance with that.

Comment: It worked, the issue was with the type of request i was sending. I was sending a patch request when i should have been sending a put request. I still don't know what the real issue was but it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have a question, what if i have an array of objects with each object having different values for the same column. How do i implement the above solution for that ?
```[{startTime: "", endTime: "", date: ""}, {startTime: "", endTime: "", date: ""}]``` something like this.

Comment: If you just want to insert rows and not update existing rows, you can insert them all with 1 query, you will need to convert your array of objects to an array of arrays first though. Here is a generic example:

const values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2]
];

connection.query("INSERT INTO my_table (name, email, n) VALUES ?", [values], (err) => {...})


The library `knex` would let you insert objects, the keys in your objects must match the column names.